# Where is IPython.frontend.terminal.embed package for Anaconda3?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda3, finite-element-analysis, ubuntu-20.10

I have pulled the source code for [SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html) from [GitHub](https://github.com/sfepy/sfepy) with the objective of building and running it locally.

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.10 using Anaconda3.  I have [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) 2020.2 from Jetbrains as my IDE.

When I bring the code into PyCharm I see several errors about missing packages.  One of them is in the `base.py` file:

```
       except NameError:
            from IPython.frontend.terminal.embed \
                 import InteractiveShellEmbed
```

The IDE tells me that the terminal package is not installed.  It is not found when I try to install.

I searched for it at [Anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org), but no joy.

This is an active code base.  There was a commit made just today.

How can it be that this code won't build?  What am I missing?  How can I find a replacement so I can build this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the [SfePy GitHub issues page](https://github.com/sfepy/sfepy/issues/659):

```
conda install sfepy
```

brings in all the dependencies.  I'm able to successfully run all the unit tests:

```
sfepy-run run_tests
```

When I open PyCharm the compilation problems are resolved.